# A space with an inner product but is not Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis

> What is an example of an inner product space which is not a Hilbert space?

I was having confusion in this.

Comment: Any infinite-dimensional inner product space that is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Take, for instance, the space of all sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real number such that $n\gg1\Longrightarrow x_n=0$ and consider the inner product$$\bigl\langle(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr\rangle=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}x_ny_n.$$